# addByteLength() not adding bytes to send message in omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

I wrote a function for my own simulation model to create and send ARP requests.
Here in the below code I have successfully created the ARP packet and set the byte size to 28. Now when I tried to encapsulate this created packet inside the link layer frame `tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame`

```
                tempIPARPRequest = new IPv4ARP("IPv4ARP Request");
                tempIPARPRequest->setSourceIP(tempIPPacket->getSourceIP());
                tempIPARPRequest->setDestinationIP(
                        tempIPPacket->getDestinationIP());
                tempIPARPRequest->addByteLength(28);
                // encapsulate it 
                tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame= new LinkLayerFrame("LinkARP Request");
                tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame->setField1(this->Field1);
                tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame->setField2(this->Field2);


                tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame->setFrameType(0); //an ARP packet
                tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame->addByteLength(30); //30Bytes
                tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame->encapsulate(tempIPARPRequest);
                tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame->setKind(0);

                send(tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame->dup(), "toBelowSendQ");
                ARPRequestedCache[tempIPPacket->getDestinationIP()] = true;
```

But I see that the transmitted frame is of size 28 bytes instead of 28 + 30 = 58 bytes. Why is it happening or the encapsulate function is not appending the bytes?

### Updated

The IPv4ARP msg file is:

NED File:

```
packet IPv4ARP {
    string SourceIP;
    string DestinationIP;
}
```

IPv4ARP_m.h:

```
//
// Generated file, do not edit! Created by nedtool 4.6 from IPv4ARP.msg.
//

#ifndef _IPV4ARP_M_H_
#define _IPV4ARP_M_H_

#include <omnetpp.h>

// nedtool version check
#define MSGC_VERSION 0x0406
#if (MSGC_VERSION!=OMNETPP_VERSION)
#    error Version mismatch! Probably this file was generated by an earlier version of nedtool: 'make clean' should help.
#endif



/**
 * Class generated from <tt>IPv4ARP.msg:19</tt> by nedtool.
 * <pre>
 * //
 * // TODO generated message class
 * //
 * packet IPv4ARP
 * {
 *     string SourceIP;
 *     string DestinationIP;
 * }
 * </pre>
 */
class IPv4ARP : public ::cPacket
{
  protected:
    opp_string SourceIP_var;
    opp_string DestinationIP_var;

  private:
    void copy(const IPv4ARP& other);

  protected:
    // protected and unimplemented operator==(), to prevent accidental usage
    bool operator==(const IPv4ARP&);

  public:
    IPv4ARP(const char *name=NULL, int kind=0);
    IPv4ARP(const IPv4ARP& other);
    virtual ~IPv4ARP();
    IPv4ARP& operator=(const IPv4ARP& other);
    virtual IPv4ARP *dup() const {return new IPv4ARP(*this);}
    virtual void parsimPack(cCommBuffer *b);
    virtual void parsimUnpack(cCommBuffer *b);

    // field getter/setter methods
    virtual const char * getSourceIP() const;
    virtual void setSourceIP(const char * SourceIP);
    virtual const char * getDestinationIP() const;
    virtual void setDestinationIP(const char * DestinationIP);
};

inline void doPacking(cCommBuffer *b, IPv4ARP& obj) {obj.parsimPack(b);}
inline void doUnpacking(cCommBuffer *b, IPv4ARP& obj) {obj.parsimUnpack(b);}


#endif // ifndef _IPV4ARP_M_H_
```

IPv4ARP_m.cc

```
//
// Generated file, do not edit! Created by nedtool 4.6 from IPv4ARP.msg.
//

// Disable warnings about unused variables, empty switch stmts, etc:
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  pragma warning(disable:4101)
#  pragma warning(disable:4065)
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "IPv4ARP_m.h"

USING_NAMESPACE


// Another default rule (prevents compiler from choosing base class' doPacking())
template<typename T>
void doPacking(cCommBuffer *, T& t) {
    throw cRuntimeError("Parsim error: no doPacking() function for type %s or its base class (check .msg and _m.cc/h files!)",opp_typename(typeid(t)));
}

template<typename T>
void doUnpacking(cCommBuffer *, T& t) {
    throw cRuntimeError("Parsim error: no doUnpacking() function for type %s or its base class (check .msg and _m.cc/h files!)",opp_typename(typeid(t)));
}




// Template rule for outputting std::vector<T> types
template<typename T, typename A>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T,A>& vec)
{
    out.put('{');
    for(typename std::vector<T,A>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it != vec.begin()) {
            out.put(','); out.put(' ');
        }
        out << *it;
    }
    out.put('}');

    char buf[32];
    sprintf(buf, " (size=%u)", (unsigned int)vec.size());
    out.write(buf, strlen(buf));
    return out;
}

// Template rule which fires if a struct or class doesn't have operator<<
template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const T&) {return out;}

Register_Class(IPv4ARP);

IPv4ARP::IPv4ARP(const char *name, int kind) : ::cPacket(name,kind)
{
    this->SourceIP_var = 0;
    this->DestinationIP_var = 0;
}

IPv4ARP::IPv4ARP(const IPv4ARP& other) : ::cPacket(other)
{
    copy(other);
}

IPv4ARP::~IPv4ARP()
{
}

IPv4ARP& IPv4ARP::operator=(const IPv4ARP& other)
{
    if (this==&other) return *this;
    ::cPacket::operator=(other);
    copy(other);
    return *this;
}

void IPv4ARP::copy(const IPv4ARP& other)
{
    this->SourceIP_var = other.SourceIP_var;
    this->DestinationIP_var = other.DestinationIP_var;
}

void IPv4ARP::parsimPack(cCommBuffer *b)
{
    ::cPacket::parsimPack(b);
    doPacking(b,this->SourceIP_var);
    doPacking(b,this->DestinationIP_var);
}

void IPv4ARP::parsimUnpack(cCommBuffer *b)
{
    ::cPacket::parsimUnpack(b);
    doUnpacking(b,this->SourceIP_var);
    doUnpacking(b,this->DestinationIP_var);
}

const char * IPv4ARP::getSourceIP() const
{
    return SourceIP_var.c_str();
}

void IPv4ARP::setSourceIP(const char * SourceIP)
{
    this->SourceIP_var = SourceIP;
}

const char * IPv4ARP::getDestinationIP() const
{
    return DestinationIP_var.c_str();
}

void IPv4ARP::setDestinationIP(const char * DestinationIP)
{
    this->DestinationIP_var = DestinationIP;
}

class IPv4ARPDescriptor : public cClassDescriptor
{
  public:
    IPv4ARPDescriptor();
    virtual ~IPv4ARPDescriptor();

    virtual bool doesSupport(cObject *obj) const;
    virtual const char *getProperty(const char *propertyname) const;
    virtual int getFieldCount(void *object) const;
    virtual const char *getFieldName(void *object, int field) const;
    virtual int findField(void *object, const char *fieldName) const;
    virtual unsigned int getFieldTypeFlags(void *object, int field) const;
    virtual const char *getFieldTypeString(void *object, int field) const;
    virtual const char *getFieldProperty(void *object, int field, const char *propertyname) const;
    virtual int getArraySize(void *object, int field) const;

    virtual std::string getFieldAsString(void *object, int field, int i) const;
    virtual bool setFieldAsString(void *object, int field, int i, const char *value) const;

    virtual const char *getFieldStructName(void *object, int field) const;
    virtual void *getFieldStructPointer(void *object, int field, int i) const;
};

Register_ClassDescriptor(IPv4ARPDescriptor);

IPv4ARPDescriptor::IPv4ARPDescriptor() : cClassDescriptor("IPv4ARP", "cPacket")
{
}

IPv4ARPDescriptor::~IPv4ARPDescriptor()
{
}

bool IPv4ARPDescriptor::doesSupport(cObject *obj) const
{
    return dynamic_cast<IPv4ARP *>(obj)!=NULL;
}

const char *IPv4ARPDescriptor::getProperty(const char *propertyname) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    return basedesc ? basedesc->getProperty(propertyname) : NULL;
}

int IPv4ARPDescriptor::getFieldCount(void *object) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    return basedesc ? 2+basedesc->getFieldCount(object) : 2;
}

unsigned int IPv4ARPDescriptor::getFieldTypeFlags(void *object, int field) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount(object))
            return basedesc->getFieldTypeFlags(object, field);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount(object);
    }
    static unsigned int fieldTypeFlags[] = {
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
        FD_ISEDITABLE,
    };
    return (field>=0 && field<2) ? fieldTypeFlags[field] : 0;
}

const char *IPv4ARPDescriptor::getFieldName(void *object, int field) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount(object))
            return basedesc->getFieldName(object, field);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount(object);
    }
    static const char *fieldNames[] = {
        "SourceIP",
        "DestinationIP",
    };
    return (field>=0 && field<2) ? fieldNames[field] : NULL;
}

int IPv4ARPDescriptor::findField(void *object, const char *fieldName) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    int base = basedesc ? basedesc->getFieldCount(object) : 0;
    if (fieldName[0]=='S' && strcmp(fieldName, "SourceIP")==0) return base+0;
    if (fieldName[0]=='D' && strcmp(fieldName, "DestinationIP")==0) return base+1;
    return basedesc ? basedesc->findField(object, fieldName) : -1;
}

const char *IPv4ARPDescriptor::getFieldTypeString(void *object, int field) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount(object))
            return basedesc->getFieldTypeString(object, field);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount(object);
    }
    static const char *fieldTypeStrings[] = {
        "string",
        "string",
    };
    return (field>=0 && field<2) ? fieldTypeStrings[field] : NULL;
}

const char *IPv4ARPDescriptor::getFieldProperty(void *object, int field, const char *propertyname) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount(object))
            return basedesc->getFieldProperty(object, field, propertyname);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount(object);
    }
    switch (field) {
        default: return NULL;
    }
}

int IPv4ARPDescriptor::getArraySize(void *object, int field) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount(object))
            return basedesc->getArraySize(object, field);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount(object);
    }
    IPv4ARP *pp = (IPv4ARP *)object; (void)pp;
    switch (field) {
        default: return 0;
    }
}

std::string IPv4ARPDescriptor::getFieldAsString(void *object, int field, int i) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount(object))
            return basedesc->getFieldAsString(object,field,i);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount(object);
    }
    IPv4ARP *pp = (IPv4ARP *)object; (void)pp;
    switch (field) {
        case 0: return oppstring2string(pp->getSourceIP());
        case 1: return oppstring2string(pp->getDestinationIP());
        default: return "";
    }
}

bool IPv4ARPDescriptor::setFieldAsString(void *object, int field, int i, const char *value) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount(object))
            return basedesc->setFieldAsString(object,field,i,value);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount(object);
    }
    IPv4ARP *pp = (IPv4ARP *)object; (void)pp;
    switch (field) {
        case 0: pp->setSourceIP((value)); return true;
        case 1: pp->setDestinationIP((value)); return true;
        default: return false;
    }
}

const char *IPv4ARPDescriptor::getFieldStructName(void *object, int field) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount(object))
            return basedesc->getFieldStructName(object, field);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount(object);
    }
    switch (field) {
        default: return NULL;
    };
}

void *IPv4ARPDescriptor::getFieldStructPointer(void *object, int field, int i) const
{
    cClassDescriptor *basedesc = getBaseClassDescriptor();
    if (basedesc) {
        if (field < basedesc->getFieldCount(object))
            return basedesc->getFieldStructPointer(object, field, i);
        field -= basedesc->getFieldCount(object);
    }
    IPv4ARP *pp = (IPv4ARP *)object; (void)pp;
    switch (field) {
        default: return NULL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Core4Inet` has a customization of `Tkenv` for console output.

The cPacket indeed gets encapsulated and the size too gets added. Whenever you reference the `Core4Inet` project it shows both the encapsulated cPacket's size as well as the parent cPacket's size [Just adjacent to it]. Check the console output properly [**If there is a horizontal scroll bar, then use it**].

Answer (score 2):

In the presented code you are sending `tempIPoIBARPRequest`, but you didn't show this variable in code. And the packet `tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame`, you expect to have 58 bytes is not sent anywhere.
To check actual size of `tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame` try:

```
EV << "size of tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame is " << tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame->getByteLength() << " bytes \n";
```

It shows that `tempLinkLayerARPRequestFrame` has size equal to 58 bytes.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have actually modified that code. Updated the question now. It is definitely not a variable issue. Because, earlier it did showed me 58 bytes. But after I made introduced other files in the same project directory and referenced INET and Core4Inet projects, it is showing only 28 bytes. I wonder how could this be possible as all the statments are just in the same sequence. So all statements should get executed

Comment: Could you show msg file of `IPv4ARP` as well as `LinkLayerFrame`?

Comment: Hi Jerzy, the msg and the auto generated files are updated. Please check it.

Comment: Jerzy, one more thing I have encountered now. Whenever, I project reference `core4inet` the encapsulation size does not work even after changing to a new msg name instead of IPv4ARP